# Node js parse twitter statuses get text

Tags: arrays, node.js, parsing, twitter

I am trying to simply get the tweets using node-twitter
https://github.com/jdub/node-twitter
I am able to parse the json correctly but I am having trouble getting to parse just the text category of each of my statuses

how do you get into the statuses array and get into the text category in json with Node js?  Thats all I want to know

so I want to parse text which is in an array of statuses.  I will need to go into the statuses array and print out every text element for each status I have

Comment: What code do you have for now? What do you get with it? Because getting the text of statuses from the JSON should be as simple as `parsedJSON.statuses.forEach(function (status) { console.log(status.text); });`

Comment: I have  .search('#Angels', function(data) {
        var json = util.inspect(data);
        var jsObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json));

        console.log(json
        );

    }

Comment: im using node twitter

Comment: Why are you calling `JSON.stringify` in order to parse it right after? This is completely useless, and you should use raw output from the library, which already takes care of parsing any JSON for you. ANyway, the piece of code I gave you in my previous comment should do the trick.

Comment: you cant do a for each loop in node js, i tried     .search('#Angels', function(data) {
        var json = util.inspect(data);
       for( var status in json.statuses)
        {
            console.log(status.text);
        }
        
    }

Comment: How can't you do a ForEach loop? V8 has support for this, and I do this every day... Anyway. Is your problem solved?